# Can I use an String array within split() to specifier delimiters?

Tags: java, arrays, split, delimiter

New to java/coding and trying to get to grips with it so thank you in advance for the help!

I have this string "s" I am splitting using a set of operators as delimiters.

`String[] workableParts = s.split("(?<=[-+*/%^=])|(?=[-+*/%^=])");`

I'm storing each split within the workableParts array with the delimiters also stored as part of the array - so for instance an input of 7+7 would be stored as:

`workableParts[0]="7"
 workableParts[1]="+"
 workableParts[2]="7"`

I also use this operator array elsewhere:

`private String[] ops = {"-","+","*","/","%","^","="};`

Is there a way I can use this to replace the text in the split above but maintain the same effect? The idea being that if I add operators at a later date I only have to update them in one place.

Many thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to convert your string array to a string using `Arrays.toString(ops);` and use that in the regex expression.
This returns the string of the form `[-,+,*,/,...]`.

Now, you can replace the `,` with an empty string `""` and use the substring in your regex.

```java
private String[] ops = {"-","+","*","/","%","^","="};
String joinedOps = Arrays.toString(strArray);
joinedOps = joinedOps.substring(1, str.length()-1).replace(",", "");
String regex = "...."+joinedOps+"...";
```

Comment: Or `"["+String.join("", ops)+"]"`. These work for the case asked, but not if `^` is the _first_ entry or `-` is in the middle. And not if `]` is an operator, which it is in C, C++, Java, python, js, gawk, and perl, and some shells. And of course not for any multi-character operator(s).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.  Define you own split method and build the regex inside of it.  When you change the ops array you will modify the regex.

Note:  You must use caution in the placement of the ops so that they don't construct an unexpected character class. E.g. `-` should be at the front and `^` should never be.

```
static String[] ops = { "-", "+", "*", "/", "%", "^", "=" };

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "7+7-8^2";

        String[] workableParts = opSplit(s);        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(workableParts));     
}
```

Prints

```
[7, +, 7, -, 8, ^, 2]
```

The method

```
public static String[] opSplit(String s) {
    String op = String.join("", ops);
    String regex = "(?<=[" + op + "])|(?=[" + op + "])";
    return s.split(regex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I needed help with - much appreciated :)